# Data Tracking in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-formatting

I'm looking for a way to write the following in Excel, but I always run in at least one trouble that makes the end result inconsistent. The user should only change the values in the B and C columns: [image: Desired End Result]

I'm making a database for Oil Changes in cars, each change must be every 10k Km. When the car reaches 9k Km, the corresponding B colum should color orange, and when it goes beyond the 10k, should be red, all of them are subject to the C column. The D and E columns should update automatically based on the values of B and C. Is this possible to do on Excel?

**EDIT** (from comment)
There are the formulas I used on the D and E columns. How can I fix them:

```
 D5: =IF(C5="No", ROUNDUP(B5/$G$1-1, 0), ROUNDUP(B5/$G$1, 0))
 E5: =IF(C5="No", $G$1*ROUNDUP(B5/$G$1-1, 0), $G$1*ROUNDUP(B5/$G$1, 0))
```

Comment: Q: *Is this possible to do on Excel?* A: Yes

Comment: There are the formulas I used on the D and E columns. How can I fix them:

D: =IF(C5="No", ROUNDUP(B5/$G$1-1, 0), ROUNDUP(B5/$G$1, 0))
E: =IF(C5="No", $G$1*ROUNDUP(B5/$G$1-1, 0), $G$1*ROUNDUP(B5/$G$1, 0))

Comment: How are the formulae not working now?  You don't actually say what it doesn't do correctly.

Comment: If the Value in C3 is changed to No, the B3 cell colors red, when it shouldn't do that. It should only change to orange when it's ~1000 to the value on the corresponding E cell (more than 19000 but less than 20000 in this case) and red if it goes above that, otherwise, it should be white. It's that small inconsistency in code/formatting that I'm having so much problems with.

Comment: It sounds like the issue is in the conditional formatting formulas and not in the cell formulas. can you show what the conditional formatting is in Cell B3 for example.

Comment: http://imgur.com/X4C6EmY
Apply format to the cells that contain:
Cell Value between $E$3-1000 and $E$3.

For the red one, it's similar except it applies the format to those above $E$3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is not the formatting. Lets look at your problem in more detail (I'll pick row 2 for formulas):

If the oil was changed, then `E2` ( or `D2` as it is just `=E2/F$1`) is above `B2` (that is easy). So the first part is correct:

```
=IF(C2="Yes",FLOOR(B2,G$1)+G$1,[???])
```

But what happens if it is changed to "no"? You want it to stay at the old value. And to do this, you need **iteration**.
Go to **Options** => **Formulas** => check the **Iteration** checkbox

Now you can do it with going for the old value of the cell by this formula for `E2`:

```
=IF(C2="Yes",FLOOR(B2,G$1)+G$1,E2)
```

Whenever `C2` is "Yes", then `E2` will jump over `B2`. Else it will stay at its old value. Just have in mind, that starting with this formula and not having "Yes", it will be "0". (so for all cars which are "good", you need to change it to "Yes" just one time).
The conditional formatting part then is very easy:

```
=B2>E2          for red
=(E2-B2)<=1000  for orange
```

[image]